# Upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04, after reboot no change

Tags: upgrade, updates, 15.04

I was using Ubuntu 14.10 (Ubuntu MATE) and my Update Manager showed up that there is an upgrade possible to 15.04.
So I selected ok and the upgrade started. It took a lot of time, but after that everything was finished and I had to restart the system.

But now everything is the same. There is no change. I checked the kernel with `uname -a` , but it's the old 14.10 kernel I think:

```
Linux i3 3.16.0-38-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 10:51:21 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I started the update manager also `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but there are no new updates. There is something fishy? Any ideas?

Edit: maybe this output can help for analysis:

```
dpkg -l | grep -Ei "linux-headers|linux-image" 
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic               3.16.0-23.31                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-33-generic               3.16.0-33.44                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic               3.16.0-34.47                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic               3.16.0-36.48                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic               3.16.0-38.52                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic               3.19.0-18.18                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic         3.16.0-23.31                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic         3.16.0-33.44                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic         3.16.0-34.47                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-36-generic         3.16.0-36.48                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic         3.16.0-38.52                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic         3.19.0-18.18                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

I see 3.19 there - but somehow when booting my system is still using 3.16, why?

Edit 2:

```
sudo apt update
Ign http://archive.canonical.com vivid InRelease
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release.gpg                          
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release                              
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease                                         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner amd64 Packages               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner i386 Packages          
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg [933 B]                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner Translation-en                    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release.gpg         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release [63,5 kB]    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Sources                    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Sources     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Sources       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted amd64 Packages   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Sources    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Sources    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en  
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en  
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en    
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources [32,4 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Sources          
Get:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources [28 B]              
Get:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources [12,6 kB]             
Get:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Sources [1.957 B]           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main amd64 Packages                       
Get:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages [75,1 kB]
Get:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted amd64 Packages                  
Get:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe amd64 Packages [40,4 kB]
Get:10 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [3.494 B]    
Get:11 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main i386 Packages [74,7 kB]            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe amd64 Packages       
Get:12 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]
Get:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe i386 Packages [40,3 kB]               
Get:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [3.680 B]                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main i386 Packages  
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Sources     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-en   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-en
Fetched 349 kB in 5s (66,5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Edit 3:

```
lsb_release -c
Codename:   vivid
```

Why is it vivid if not even the kernel is correct?

Edit 4:

Ok `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` did solve the problem. After that I rebooted and now I have the current(?) kernel:

```
uname -a
Linux i3 3.19.0-18-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 19 18:31:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I still don't understand why my system was using the old kernel after the upgrade to 15.04 (maybe somebody can explain?) but I hope now everything is fine. Thx for helping!

full output

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-18 linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic linux-image-generic thermald
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.19.0 linux-source-3.19.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-18 linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic linux-image-generic thermald
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 65,5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 290 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic amd64 3.19.0-18.18 [16,8 MB]
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic amd64 3.19.0-18.18 [38,4 MB]
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main linux-image-generic amd64 3.19.0.18.17 [2.448 B]
Get:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main linux-headers-3.19.0-18 all 3.19.0-18.18 [9.323 kB]
Get:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic amd64 3.19.0-18.18 [752 kB]
Get:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main linux-headers-generic amd64 3.19.0.18.17 [2.418 B]
Get:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main linux-generic amd64 3.19.0.18.17 [1.848 B]
Get:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main thermald amd64 1.3-9 [184 kB]
Fetched 65,5 MB in 12s (5.254 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic.
(Reading database ... 151653 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic_3.19.0-18.18_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic (3.19.0-18.18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic_3.19.0-18.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic (3.19.0-18.18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_3.19.0.18.17_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (3.19.0.18.17) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.19.0-18.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.19.0-18_3.19.0-18.18_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.19.0-18 (3.19.0-18.18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic_3.19.0-18.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic (3.19.0-18.18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_3.19.0.18.17_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (3.19.0.18.17) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_3.19.0.18.17_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (3.19.0.18.17) ...
Selecting previously unselected package thermald.
Preparing to unpack .../thermald_1.3-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking thermald (1.3-9) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.12-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic (3.19.0-18.18) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic (3.19.0-18.18) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
Setting up linux-image-generic (3.19.0.18.17) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.19.0-18 (3.19.0-18.18) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic (3.19.0-18.18) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.19.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Setting up linux-headers-generic (3.19.0.18.17) ...
Setting up linux-generic (3.19.0.18.17) ...
Setting up thermald (1.3-9) ...
invoke-rc.d: Unit thermald.service is masked
```

Maybe just grub was not updated and that was the only problem

Comment: Post the output of this command   >>    lsb_release -a

Comment: Yet another suggestion: try going to `Software & Updates` from the Dash and changing the update server to a different one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel 3.19 is not installed for some reason. Run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

and it will be fixed.

Comment: I think it's there actually (see the logs) it's just not default because the OP's got old kernals installed still, `sudo apt-get autoremove` should fix it.

Comment: It is default with those repositories. Meta package probably is not installed.

Comment: But it's clearly installed but not being used?

Comment: It is clearly NOT installed. But can be installed from the repos.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes I used now sudo apt-get install linux-generic and restarted and now there is the new kernel "3.19.0-18-generic"

Answer (score 1):

If your release upgrade was interrupted,try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If still blocked, try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh
```

If all that leads to no result, it means the release upgrade didn't happen.
To launch it properly :

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

(*apt-get dist-upgrade* just leads to a package upgrade with dependencies, not a release upgrade. From 14.04 on you can use the less confusing **sudo apt full-upgrade** for upgrades with dependencies)

Comment: I dont think the upgrade was interrupted, because everything was installed fine and in the text was "done" I just have to restart. I tried sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install but no change. Also tried sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt update
sudo do-release-upgrade but I get the message "Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found" and "sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Comment: What is the complete outcome of  `sudo apt update`  ? Does it mention only vivid or do you have utopic leftovers ? could be interesting to know which kernels are installed  `dpkg -l | grep -Ei "linux-headers|linux-image" `

Comment: Hmm. What release does the login terminal say it is? (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` to check and `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F7` to switch back) also as bagustris said, lsb_release -a would be useful

Comment: Maybe the MATE devs messed up something. 14.10 was no official ubuntu flavour, for 15.04 things changed - probably the update manager got buggy and ignored stuff.

Comment: @nam1962 apt update gives me: "Reading package lists... Done                
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date."  I updated my post up, here I cannot format

Comment: @Ads20000 nothing, with ctrl alt f1 I just get a black screen, no terminal no nothing. I can switch back with f7 and try again but still nothing.

Comment: @Lis: The `...` part is what's important. What URLs is it reading? Also, what is the output of `lsb_release -c`?

Comment: @saiarcot895 I updated the output. The lsb_release -c gives me "Codename: vivid". But as I posted, I have still the old kernel... ?

Comment: The ... is always printed before it says done @saiarcot895 I think that's fine.

Comment: @Lis it says you've got the new 3.19 kernal you just need to run `sudo apt-get autoremove`? Also, does it REALLY matter?

Comment: @Ads20000 I thought the new kernel is in every version the most important thing and biggest change. That is why I thought if there is still the old 3.16 I did not updated correctly...

Comment: As far as I know you have to use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove the old kernals though, the logs you posted show that the new kernal is installed!

Comment: @Ads20000: It's not installed. The `rc` indicates that there are configuration files **remaining** (as in, a partial uninstall).

Comment: Hmm, that complicates things. Hopefully just running the install Linux command in the other answer will fix it, otherwise what to do next?

Comment: autoremove did not help somehow BUT as Pilot posted "sudo apt-get install linux-generic" solved the problem. Thank you for the help and sorry for confusion. I hope my 15.04 is now as it should be(?) and I dont have to do other things